# Cannot create PhoneAuthCredential without either verificationProof, sessionInfo, temporary proof, or enrollment ID,other solutions not meeting the sol

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, firebase-authentication

1. I have been working on firebase phone authentication, I just want to verify the users device.
   on getting the 6 digit code, it ought to verify the phone but its not verifying.
   the error message is-  Cannot create PhoneAuthCredential without either verificationProof, sessionInfo, temporary proof, or enrollment ID.
2. I have uploaded the SHA 1 in the console, on sending the phone number am getting the code and the verificationID is not null

```
  // Initialize phone auth callbacks-[start]
        callBacks = object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
            override fun onVerificationCompleted(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onVerificationCompleted: $credential")
                signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential)
            }

            override fun onVerificationFailed(e: FirebaseException) {
                progressDialog.dismiss()
                Log.w(TAG, "onVerificationFailed", e)
                if (e is FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException){
                    setToast("Invalid OTP",1)
                }
            }

            override fun onCodeSent(
                verificationId: String,
                token: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken
            ) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCodeSent:$verificationId")
                // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
                storedVerificationId = verificationId
                resendToken = token
                progressDialog.dismiss()
               // super.onCodeSent(verificationId, token)
            }

        }
        //phone auth callbacks-[End]

 //Starting the Verification-sending the phone number-inside onCreate
        val number = "+91 ${enteredNumber}"
        startPhoneNumberVerification(number)

 //Fun to send the ph number for verification[START]- 1
    private fun startPhoneNumberVerification(phoneNumber: String) {
        progressDialog.setMessage("Getting the OTP..")
        progressDialog.show()

        val options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(auth)
            .setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
            .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .setActivity(this)
            .setCallbacks(callBacks)
            .build()
        PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)
    }
    //Fun to send the ph number for verification[END]

 //Verifying Code [START]-2
    private fun verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(verificationId: String?, code: String) {
        try {
            progressDialog.setMessage("Verifying Phone Number..")
            progressDialog.show()
            val credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId!!,code)
            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential)
        }
        catch (e:Exception){
            setToast("verifyPhoneNumberWithCode error",1)
            binding.txtErrorMsgs.text="verifyPhoneNumberWithCode error"
            Log.d(TAG,e.toString())
        }

    }
    //Verifying Code [END]

 

    // [START sign_in_with_phone]-3
    private fun signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential: PhoneAuthCredential){
         //  FirebaseAuth.getInstance().
         auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this){task->
                if (task.isSuccessful){
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success")
                    val user=task.result?.user?.phoneNumber
                    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
                else{
                    // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI
                        progressDialog.dismiss()
                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.exception)
                    if (task.exception is FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException){
                        progressDialog.dismiss()
                        setToast("Invalid OTP",1)
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    // [END sign_in_with_phone]
```